# Hooks and a MY_Model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was hoping I could find someone that could answer a question for me. I'm Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model and curious to know if I can use it functionality if I need to run a function from it inside of a hook.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class'    => 'Logins_model',
    'function' => 'pre_init', // Run some sort of get function here
    'filename' => 'logins_model.php',
    'filepath' => 'models',
    //'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
);
```

EDIT 2 : Would you say that this is an okay hook or have I lost all grasp of this?

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_hook {

    private $CI;

    function __construct() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function validate_user() {
        $this->CI->load->model('logins_model', 'login'); //Alternatively put this in autoload.php
        $this->CI->load->model('users_model', 'user');

        $user_id = $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id');

        if (($user_id !== TRUE) && (!is_numeric($user_id)) && (strlen($user_id) < 5))
        {
            redirect('login');
        }

        $user_data = $this->CI->user->get($user_id);
        $user_data->login =  $this->CI->login->get_by('user_id', $user_id);

        if (empty($user_data))
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have created should result an infinite redirect loop. I'd create MY_Controller instead of using a hook for this, extend other controllers from it & let the login url open for non logged-in users so it won't loop for ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not using the code that you suggest. You need to create your own custom hook class and then load (or autoload) and call your model there.

It is also important to note that this will *not* work for `pre_controller` hooks as the CodeIgniter object is not yet available. The hook must be `post_controller_constructor` or later. Take this hook class for example for `hooks/some_hook.php`.

```
class some_hook {

    private $CI;

    function __construct() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function some_function() {
        $this->CI->load->model('logins_model'); //Alternatively put this in autoload.php
        $this->CI->logins_model->some_function_in_logins();
    }
}
```

Then you would load it using:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'some_hook',
    'function' => 'some_function',
    'filename' => 'some_hook.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Comment: Thats if you don't "extend" the class.. which is an option

Comment: @chris Extending the model class and calling it via. a hook only works if you don't need any future persistent access to that instance of the model. Once a class executed by a hook finishes running you don't have a handle to that class anymore meaning that any member variables that you set during the hook are lost. By creating a wrapper class and instantiating the model within it, the handle to that model instance is preserved through the CodeIgniter superobject which allows access to it again later in execution.

Comment: I was asking this question because I have a control panel that before it gets loaded I would like to run a few tests like to see if there is a session active as well as if that passes then verify that the user_id is valid by running a few tests on that and if those don't pass then redirect to the login screen but also would like like to run counts on some items in my database. If your saying that it should be post controller how could that be if I need it to run before the controller loads.

Comment: @user2576961 The code I posted can do this, just run your checks and handle the results accordingly in the `some_hook` class. If you need to save persistent information which can then be accessed by the controller you can do it using member variables in your `logins_model` model. The `post_controller_constructor` hook point means that the constructor for the controller has run, but whatever controller function your page is using hasn't run yet.

Comment: Oh alright. I'll give it ago and maybe come back here if I run into an issue.

Comment: That should work, although you need to change the hook call in hooks.php so that it will work. However you also need to check to make sure you're not already loading the login controller, otherwise you'll get stuck in an infinite redirect loop. Just a suggestion though, if this isn't needed on every page on the site (save login) you might be better off making a helper and calling that in the functions that you need to check a user's session on. As a hook this will protect every page across the whole site.